# HTML get method wont send data to PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

Data inside my form will not send to `search.php`.

```
<form class="form-search" action="search.php" method="get">
    <input type="text">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>


// search.php
<h2>Searched <?php print $_GET['username']; ?>; Returned 5 Results from Query.</h2>
```

> Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\Web\Statistics\search.php on line 40

Therefore, the data was not set in `$_GET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a name to the input

```
<input type="text" name='username' placeholder="Username" id="username" class="input-medium search-query">
```

$_GET works based on the Input name not the ID. Name is passed when you press submit, ID just identifies the input on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need name="username" in addition to all of the other attributes you've specified.

Answer (score 0):

your form should look like

```
 <form class="form-search" action="search.php" method="get">
      <fieldset>
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" class="input-medium search-query">
      <button type="submit" id="srchUser" class="btn">Search</button>
      </fieldset>
  </form>
```

I've added to your input `name="username"` so it can send get variables to php by using the name attribute in input items